# Add asterisk to the required field label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a (unchangable) form structure like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        <label for="frm-registrationForm-form-surname">Surname:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input class="form-control text" id="registration-form-surname" type="text" name="surname" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there possible to add the asterisk `*` sign next to all the labels relying to the inputs with "required" attribute using the CSS? I did not find any option to link the input with the label in CSS even in the same form group.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with pure CSS

Comment: If you want a CSS-only solution, that is not possible because (1) this requires traversing **up** the DOM tree, which is not supported in CSS (maybe in CSS4), but (2) this requires traversing **to a previous sibling**, which is for the same reason not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery.

**First solution.** If .form-group has only one input and label elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[required]').parents('.form-group').find('label').append('*');
});
```

**Second solution.** Working only of your label **for** and input **id** attributes the same

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[required]").each(function(index) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('label[for="'+id+'"]').append('*');
  });
});
```

I would recommend you to use the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to implement this functionality. Inside document.ready function,

```
  var str ='*';
  $(".control-label").append(str);
```

Entire script would be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var str ='*';
  $(".control-label").append(str);
});
```